# Setting a function variable from jQuery AJAX result

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm doing a GET request with jQuery inside of a function and trying to set a variable declared earlier in that function with the result. However, it comes up as undefined. Am I missing the concept here? How can I make something like this work? Thanks.

```
function doSomething1() {
    var x;
    $.get( window.location.href, { q: 'stuff', q2: $('input').val() }, function(data){
        // value shows up 
        console.log(data);
        x = data;
    });
    return x;
}

function doSomething2() {
      // comes up as undefined.
      console.log(doSomething1());
}

doSomething2();
```

Comment: your return is been called before the response comes from your ajax call, once it's asynchronous . that's why your `x` is undefined

Comment: I also tried putting the "return x" inside of the callback function. Seems like that would be logical, but didn't matter. I will take a look at the duplicate. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fault of the asynchronous effect of $.get() requests. You are returning `x` before the get has a chance to do anything. It takes a while to wrap your head around async functions.

The order of events is as follows:

1. `doSomething2()` calls `doSomething1()`
2. `doSomething1()` defines `x` without a value begins the GET request, and returns `undefined`.
3. `doSomething2()` logs the returned `x` value
4. The GET request finishes and processes its success function

Comment: What is the reason for it not working when I put the return in the callback of the GET request?

Comment: If your function waited on the GET to finish before continuing, then there would be a delay. Your initiating function continues on as the GET request runs in parallel, and you have to prepare for when it finishes separately. You already use `console.log(data)` within the success function—that is where you should handle tasks requiring this data.

Comment: Thanks. That makes. So it looks like either I have to handle the data in the callback itself, or pass it into another function from within the callback that will handle it.